# Graphql express nested schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, graphql

I am currently building mern + graphql app. I am new to graphql and I have two different models a User Model and Character model. The Character Model is nested in the User. When I create a user in the Graphiql interface I want it to display its data and the character that is associated with the specific user but instead it is displaying every character that has been created in the database and adding them to every user created instead of the specific user. Trying to figure out how to fix this. [Link to Github Repo](https://github.com/flmngwllm/StatTracker)

**Mongoose User Model**

```
const mongoose = require('../db/connection')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const User = new Schema({
    id: String,
    name: String,
    totalwins: Number,
    description: String,
    charactersID: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Character"
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User)
```

**Mongoose Character Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Character = new Schema({
    name: String,
    wins: Number,
    losses: Number,
    percentage: Number,
    image: String

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Character', Character)
```

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const { GraphQLSchema, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLInt, GraphQLID, GraphQLList, 
GraphQLNonNull } = graphql
const Character = require("../models/Character")
const User = require("../models/User")
```

**Types**

```
// User Schema
const userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'User',
fields : () => ({
    _id: {type: GraphQLID},
    name : { type: GraphQLString},
    totalwins : { type: GraphQLInt },
    description :  { type: GraphQLString },
    character : {
        type : new GraphQLList(characterType),
        resolve(parent, args){
            return Character.find({charactersID: parent.id})

        }
    }

})
})



// Character Schema
const characterType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Character',
fields : () => ({
    id: {type: GraphQLID},
    name : { type: GraphQLString},
    wins : { type: GraphQLInt },
    losses :  { type: GraphQLInt },
    percentage: {type: (GraphQLInt)},
    image: { type: GraphQLString },
})
})
```

**Query**

```
//query the graph to grab the data
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Query',
fields: {
    user : {
        type: userType,
        // arguments passed by the user while making the query
        args: {id : {type : GraphQLID}},
        resolve(parent, args){

            // return User.find((item) => { return item.id == args.id});
            //finding a single user by id
            return User.findById(args.id)

        }
    },

    users : {
        type: new GraphQLList(userType),
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return User.find({})
        }
    },

    character : {
        type: characterType,
        args: {id : {type : GraphQLID}},
        resolve(parent, args){

            return Character.findById(args.id)
        }
    },

    characters : {
        type: new GraphQLList(characterType),
        resolve(parent, args) {
            return Character.find({})
        }
    }


}
})
```

**Mutations**

```
 //allows user to add, update and delete to mondodb through graphql
 const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'Mutation',
 fields: {
    addUser: {
        type: userType,
        args: {
            name: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
            totalwins: {type: (GraphQLInt)},
            description: {type: (GraphQLString)},
            charactersID: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)}
        },
        resolve(parent, args){
            let user = new User({
                name: args.name,
                totalwins: args.totalwins,
                description: args.description,
                charactersID: args.charactersID

            })
            return user.save()

        }


    },

    addCharacter: {
        type: characterType,
        args: {
            name: {type: GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
            wins: {type: (GraphQLInt)},
            losses: {type: (GraphQLInt)},
            percentage: {type: (GraphQLInt)},
            image: {type: (GraphQLString)},

        },
        resolve(parent, args){
            let character = new Character({
                name: args.name,
                wins: args.wins,
                losses: args.losses,
                percentage: args.percentage,
                image: args.image
            })
            return character.save()

        }
    },

    deleteUser: {
        type: userType,
        args: {
            id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
        },
        resolve(parent, args){
                const remUser = User.findByIdAndRemove(args.id)
                if(!remUser){
                    throw new Error('No character found')
            }
            return remUser

        }
    },

    deleteCharacter: {
        type: characterType,
        args: {
            id: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
        },
        resolve(parent, args){
                const remCharacter = Character.findByIdAndRemove(args.id)
                if(!remCharacter){
                    throw new Error('No character found')
            }
            return remCharacter

        }
    },
}
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({ query : Query, mutation : Mutation})
```

[Image of results from Grapiql interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgdCN.png)

Comment: `return Character.find({charactersID: parent.id})` - no parent, bad find argument

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give a little more insight on how I would write a better function/ argument or what I need to do.

Comment: ...I don't know exactly ... but for sure you need `charactersID` first ... check if already here ... console.log( this.charactersID ); ... if works use it to find characters (mongo parts)... if not... use `args.id` to find User.findById ... then `charactersID`